# Wait for other interaction to happen before resolving RSVP

Tags: javascript, ajax, ember.js

I have a component that on a swipe will send an action upward to the parent route/controller to handle some ajax functionality. This component has some UI that gets set to a loading state to show the user things are happening. When working gets set back to false the loading animation in UI stops and user interaction can happen again.

```
callAjaxAction() {
  this.setProperties({working:true});
  Ember.RSVP.cast(this.attrs.action()).finally(() => {
    this.$('.draggable').animate({
      left: 0
    });
    this.setProperties({working:false});
  });
}
```

In this case the controller catches the action specified on the component definition and calls an ajax function to get some data to display in the page

```
// in the controller action
return Ember.RSVP.Promise((resolve,reject) => {
    Ember.$.ajax({
      type: 'get',
      dataType: 'json',
      url: `http://***/api/paysources/user/697?key=${ENV.APP.api_key}`
    }).then((response)=>{
      this.setProperties({
        'cards':response.user_paysources,
        'showCards': true
      });
    },(reason)=>{
      reject();
      this.get('devlog').whisper(reason);
    })
  })
```

This will show a new popup type of component that will allow the user to pick a card to pay with. If the user clicks away, or if they click a card and the ajax action completes I need to reset the UI not only on this page (change it so it says the cart has been paid for) but also send the swipe component (the one that now has a loading animation) something that tells it it's done loading.

Basically, the way I see it in my head, is there a way to fire an action on a component from the parent controller/route?

Comment: Nitpick, you're missing `new` in `new Ember.RSVP.Promise(…`

Answer (score 0):

To answer your question "is there a way to fire an action on a component from the parent controller/route?": No there is not. However there are two idiomatic ways I can think of for doing this in Ember:

1. You could potentially get around it by moving the Ajax request into the component.
2. Follow the ['data down, actions up' pattern](http://www.samselikoff.com/blog/data-down-actions-up/). See the following as an example of how to implement it.

You could fire an action on the `card` component that changes a property on your controller. Then listen to that property into the original component so it can update.

**original-component.js**

```
reset: computed('transactionComplete', function() {
  // cleanup stuff here...
})
```

**original-component-template.hbs**

```
{{#if transactionComplete}}
  {{! stuff to show when transaction is complete... }}
{{/if}}
```

**controller.js**

```
transactionComplete: false,

actions: {
  completeTransaction() {
    this.toggleProperty('transactionComplete');
  }
}
```

**controller-template.hbs**

```
{{original-component
  transactionComplete=transactionComplete
}}

{{cart-component
  transactionComplete=(action 'completeTransaction')
}}
```

**cart-component.js**

```
actions: {
  processTransaction() {
    // cleanup stuff here...
    this.attrs.transactionComplete();
  }
}
```

There might be different – and better – ways of doing this, but it depends on exactly what you need to do when resetting the original component.

Also, separately, have you considered using ember data and routing for loading the cards?

Comment: I'm going to update my question to try to illustrate better my setup

Comment: I've updated my response above based on the edits to your question.